# Why X509Certificate2 error reading private key in Windows Server 2016, works on W10

Tags: firebase, openssl, private-key, x509certificate2, service-accounts

I have created a .pfx certificate, with openssl from a certificate file and a private key, on a Mac

I use it in a .Net Core 2.1 project and I read it with:

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(fileName, password);
```

Then I use it in a function that signs a JWT token.
In windows 10 it works correctly.

But in Windows Server 2016, the certificate is not read correctly and an error occurs when trying to use it to sign (it reads from disk), if debug the program, when analyzing the PrivateKey property of the certificate, i see that it contains an exception (In Windows 10 contains a value).

And now comes the strangest:

If you import the certificate into the system (It appears correctly in the certificate store with the private key) and export it back to a new pfx file and use this file it works correctly.

Why does this happen, is it a bug in openssl or in windows?

Here information how get the certificate, it is from firebase project service account, here a python code for get .pem and .key, then use openssl for create the pfx

```
import io
import urllib.request
import json,ssl
#Fix for no SSL Validation
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
#Here the filename of service account w/o ext, downloaded from then Firebase project
service_account="service_account"
with open(service_account+".json", encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
    data = json.loads(data_file.read())
#read the data must replace the literal \n    
private_key=data["private_key"].replace("\\n", "\n")
#print(private_key)
#Get the url for get the cetificate data
client_x509_cert_url=data["client_x509_cert_url"]
with urllib.request.urlopen(client_x509_cert_url, context=ctx) as url:
    clientData = json.loads(url.read())
#The private key id for get the certificate
private_key_id=data["private_key_id"]
#read the certificate must replace the the literal \n
certificate=clientData[private_key_id].replace("\\n", "\n") 
#save then certificate
with open(service_account+".pem", "w") as pem_file:
    pem_file.write(certificate)  
#save the key
with open(service_account+".key", "w") as key_file:
    key_file.write(private_key)  
print("Done.")
```

Comment: Please share the error message

Comment: Some like (this is a free translation, my system is in spanish) System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException file not found, another clue is when work properly then certificate.PrivateKey contains a System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng class, when don work contains the excepction

Comment: @FRL how did you create this pfx?

Comment: Yes and Not, I have commented on the first line, it is created from a cer (--- BEGIN CERT ---....) and a key file (--- BEGIN PRIVATE KEY ---...) with openssl on a MAC computer, but dont create the .crt ann .key files,If I import them into the windows or mac certificate store, it is displayed correctly with its associated key, and in windows 10 it works correctly. It's a problem that I only find in WS2016